# SSRS - Display Tablix row in two places

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, epicorerp

I am trying to modify a check form so that a table of information shows up in two locations on each page instead of one location:

ex: user prints two checks printed at once. The tablix on the report returns rows of invoices for each check in the middle of the form. We want these rows of invoices to show up in two places for each check (group).

**current:**

> Check A has table A in the middle of the page
>
> Check B has table B in the middle of the page

[image: Current SSRS -- tablix with one grouping (by check) and a detail row for each invoice the check is paying off]

**desired:**

> Check A has table A in the middle and table A on the bottom
>
> Check B has table B in the middle and table B on the bottom

[image: Tablix is repeated on the body of the reports, in the hopes that it would return the same data for each page.]

I tried duplicating the tablix that displays this information (more or less copying the current tablix and pasting it underneath) but what I get is:

**actual:**

> Check A has table A in the middle
>
> Check B has table A in the middle, table B on the bottom
>
> Check C has table B in the middle

It looks like the first tablix prints all it's groupings, then the second tablix takes over and starts printing it's stuff, almost doubling the number of necessary pages (15 checks would make 29 checks with one page having the last group of the first tablix in one table, and the first group of the next tablix

I've also tried adding a row below the original tablix, both inside and outside the group. What I get is either the last row of the table repeating, or each row repeating within the table.

**current:**

> Check A, table A has row 1, row 2 in the middle

**desired:**

> Check A, table A has row 1, row 2 in the middle; table A has row 1, row 2 on bottom

**actual:**

> Check A, table A has row 1, row 2, row 2 in the middle

or

> Check A, table A has row 1, row 2, row 1, row 2 in the middle

[image: First two pages, Tablix A and B with the 'additional tablix row' attempt]]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a List container. Put all of your header, tablix and footer information into the List Container (just once). Group by the Check with a page break after each group.